# How to fix "Undefined property: stdClass::$gamme"

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I am new in the Laravel this is my first app. I have 2 tables:

**art**

```
-id
-code
-designation
-prix
-qte
-gamme_id
```

**gamme**

```
-id
-type
```

I have a relation between them

**artmodel**
[image]

**gamme_model**
[image]

and I want to search article by "code"

**search function in the controller**
[image]

**The problem is here**
[image]

**This is my index file**
[image: This is my index file]

I try to replace
`<td>{{ $row->gamme->type }}</td>` to `<td>{{ $row->gamme_id}}</td>`

And it works but I don't want to see the id of gamme:

[image: its gamme_id but I want the name of gamme]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please don't put up pictures of code, code is text, add it to the question as text in a code block not an image

Comment: you are not using your models in that query you are using query builder, so no relationships and no models returned, query builder returns `stdClass` objects

Comment: this is my gamme migration
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gammes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('type');
            
        });
    }

Comment: lagbox xhat do i need to do ?

Comment: Your Models and Migrations look fine but you might want to get the relationship between Art and Gamme when you retrieve the art data. Please take a look at Eager Loading docs `https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading`. Something like `Art::where('code', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->with('gamme')->paginate(5);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```php
$data = Art::where('code','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: @Hassen can you add `dd(Art::where('code', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->with('gamme')->get());` just before the `return` statement in your controller and show us the result please?

Comment: empty result :((

Comment: ohhh its working guys with $data = Art::where('code','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);